# how can i access a global variable in different function i lua

Tags: function, lua, global-variables

```lua
arr = {}

function Data(a)
    arr = a    
    return a
end

function create(arr)
    print(arr) -- no output
end
```

How can use access `arr` in `create()`?

Comment: Are you actually calling `create`? If so, please include the code where you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Making `create` take a parameter called `arr` hides the global `arr` within it. Either rename or remove the parameter, or use `_G.arr` or `_ENV.arr` to access the global.